# i can use phpqrcode libraby in laravel ? https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

i try to use phpqrcode library in laravel project this package is very popular , this is her link
https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpqrcode/
i use class qrCode in controller but i got this error
message
:
"Class "QRcode" not found"
[error when i use phpqrcode class in laravel framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DB2r.png)

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0go6.png)

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $input =  $request->all();
       // include(app_path().'/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
        $code = $request->email ;
        $filename ='test' . md5($code) . '.png';
        QRcode::png($code, \public_path("temp/$filename"));
        $input['qr_code']= $filename;
        Participant::create($input);
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success','message'=>'participant saved succefully !' ],201);

    }
```

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: It depends on how you've installed it. If you've installed it via Composer, then you may just need to do `composer autodump` and make sure you import the class properly. If you downloaded it and stuck it in your project, you may have to map the class properly.

Comment: no anyber he not installable from composer , is a php native code

Comment: And if you've just `require`d the library, `\QRcode::png` should do it. The \ is important.

Comment: @EmraneKlaaï Not being installable via Composer tends to be a bad sign - usually an ancient, no longer maintained package. Consider a more modern one like https://github.com/endroid/qr-code.

Comment: Just because it's PHP Native code doesn't mean that it can't be installed from Composer. I'm using a PHP QR library that is installable via Composer - bacon/bacon-qr-code and pragmarx/google2fa-laravel

Comment: What does PHP native code even mean? :)

Comment: I recommend to use Simple QrCode(https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode). Too easy to install in laravel project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How did you proceed with the installation of the lib into your project?

The lib documentation has some steps that you should follow in order to get started.Please check on the INSTALL FILE.

[image: screenshot from the lib install file]

Personally, I would recommend you use a dependency installed from composer.

Some popular ones can be found at packagist. Try out [this](https://qrcode-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as it is well documented

Comment: You are welcome dear bro

Comment: OP will still have the same issue, because of namespaces within a Laravel controller. Each of these lines will need to be revised to `\QRcode::`.